# how to use ManyToManyField as tags in my blog

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

i want add `tags` in my article and when user click on some tag it will show all articles that having that tag , so i create tag model then i add `ManyToManyField` field in `mobile model`

so what next ? i mean how to use tags when i add some tag in admin panel and how to create html page for every tag ?

model.py :

```
# Tag model 

class Tag(models.Model):
    PostTagName = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField(default="",blank=True,unique=True,editable=True)
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.id or not self.slug:
            super(Tag, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
            self.slug = slugify(f"{self.PostTagName}")
        super(Tag, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.PostTagName

# mobile model

class Mobile(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100,default="")
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100,default="")
    app_contect = RichTextField(blank=True,null=True)
    app_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/',null=True, blank=True)
    post_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True, blank=True)
    post_tag = models.CharField(max_length=50,default="",choices = MOBILE_SECTION)
    tag = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)

    NETWORK = models.TextField(max_length=240,default="")
    LAUNCH = models.TextField(max_length=240,default="")
    BODY = models.TextField(max_length=240,default="")
    DISPLAY = models.TextField(max_length=240,default="")
    PLATFORM = models.TextField(max_length=240,default="")
    MEMORY = models.TextField(max_length=240,default="")
    MAIN_CAMERA = models.TextField(max_length=240,default="")
    SELFIE_CAMERA = models.TextField(max_length=240,default="")
    SOUND = models.TextField(max_length=240,default="")
    COMMS = models.TextField(max_length=240,default="")
    FEATURES = models.TextField(max_length=240,default="")
    BATTERY = models.TextField(max_length=240,default="")
    Colors = models.TextField(max_length=240,default="")
    Price = models.CharField(max_length=240,default="")
    objects = SearchManager()
    slug = models.SlugField(default="",blank=True,unique=True,editable=True)
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.id or not self.slug:
            super(Mobile, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
            self.slug = slugify(f"{self.title}")
        super(Mobile, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_image(self):
        if self.app_image and hasattr(self.app_image, 'url'):
            return self.app_image.url
        else:
            return '/path/to/default/image'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-post_date',)
```

Comment: Please be specific when you say - **so what next?** Explain in detail.

Comment: i mean how to use tags when i add some tag in admin panel and how to create html page for every tag and how to add posts to tag page when i add it from admin panel

Comment: for example i want to add post and add tag called ' usa  ' when i save record i want add post to ' usa  tag page  ' Automatically and when user click on ' usa '  tag it will show all posts that have 'usa' tag